# How to check if minimal Debian was installed after the fact?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

Is there a way to check if minimal Debian 11 was installed after the installation was completed?

[image]

I want to know if standard system utilities or SSH server was selected during installation. The server is headless so obviously There are no Desktop environments.

Comment: How do you count installing only standard system utilities at setup and then installing SSH server after the system has been running a while. We also have headless systems that run a desktop environment for users to remote desktop into. Your assumption is good for your environment but is not universal.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `debconf` values stored in `/var/log/installer/cdebconf`.  This may depend on the installer, but works for me with a *debian-installer* based installer.

```
apt-get -y install debconf-utils
debconf-get-selections --installer | grep -E 'pkgsel|tasksel'
```

Based on the [installation guide section on package selection](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs04.en.html#preseed-pkgsel) the debconf item that matches directly to your screenshot is `tasksel/first`.  However, other items  (like `pkgsel/include`) can also install software during the installation.

Comment: I am getting an error `debconf: DbDriver "di_questions": could not open` when I execute `sudo debconf-get-selections --installer | grep -E 'pkgsel|tasksel'`

Comment: @Cruise5 does the server have the directory `/var/log/installer/cdebconf`?  Googling your error suggests it is likely missing.  Without that directory I do not know how to get the installation settings.

Comment: No such directory. Can't we look at packages that are part of standard system utilites only and see if they are installed ? This is for a newly created server and not where packages where manually installed.

Comment: I think you just want `tasksel --list-task`.  It will list the available "tasks" with either `u` (uninstalled) or `i` (installed).